# Filter a pandas series of dates that fall between the duration of two other series of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a data frame `df1` that looks like the following:

```
StartDate      EndDate
2017-01-10    2017-03-31
2017-04-10    2017-06-30
2017-07-24    2017-09-18
2017-09-30    2017-12-04
```

and `df2` that looks like this:

```
RecordDate      Grade
2017-02-10       93
2017-04-10       88
2017-09-18       89
2018-02-30       96
```

How can I merge the `df2['Grade']` to `df1` for the rows that has a `df2['RecordDate']` between the duration of `df1['StartDate']` and `df1['EndDate']` so that it can look like this:

```
StartDate      EndDate     RecordDate      Grade
2017-01-10    2017-03-31   2017-02-10       93
2017-04-10    2017-06-30   2017-04-10       88
2017-07-24    2017-09-18   2017-09-18       89
2017-09-30    2017-12-04      nan           nan
```

I tried the following code:

```
# removing time for df1 dates
df1['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime((pd.to_datetime(df1['StartDate']).dt.date)
df1['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime((pd.to_datetime(df1['EndDate']).dt.date)

df2['RecordDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['RecordDate'])

df1.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1['StartDate'],df1['EndDate'],closed='both')
df1['Grade'] = df2['RecordDate'].apply(lambda x : df1.iloc[df1index.get_loc(x, tolerance = 3)]['Grade'])
```

But I receive an error that looks like the following:

```
TypeError: category, object, and string subtypes are not supported for IntervalIndex
```

Comment: Not an R question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using `numpy`, which runs faster than `pandasql` in python.

```
# 3 day tolerance when matching
tolerance = np.timedelta64(3,'D')

start = df1.StartDate.values
end = df1.EndDate.values
target = df2.RecordDate.values

i, j = np.where((target[:, None] >= start-tolerance) & (target[:, None] <= end+tolerance))

df = pd.concat([
     df2.iloc[i, :].reset_index(drop=True),
     df1.iloc[j, :].reset_index(drop=True)
     ], axis=1)
```

```
    StartDate   EndDate     RecordDate  Grade
0   2017-01-10  2017-03-31  2017-02-10  93.0
1   2017-04-10  2017-06-30  2017-04-10  88.0
2   2017-07-24  2017-09-18  2017-09-18  89.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pandasql for it

```
from pandasql import sqldf

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())


q = """SELECT
        df.StartDate, df.EndDate,
        df2.RecordDate, df2.Grade
     FROM
        df
     LEFT JOIN
        df2
     ON df2.RecordDate >= df.StartDate 
      and  df2.RecordDate <= df.EndDate;"""

pysqldf(q)
```

```
    StartDate   EndDate     RecordDate  Grade
0   2017-01-10  2017-03-31  2017-02-10  93.0
1   2017-04-10  2017-06-30  2017-04-10  88.0
2   2017-07-24  2017-09-18  2017-09-18  89.0
3   2017-09-30  2017-12-04  None    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! I am wondering if we can modify it to have some tolerances when matching dates? Like the code in my question.